# How the YouTube video is added in Cordova application?

Tags: cordova

```
 <div onclick="thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo'); thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'">
                <img style="cursor: pointer;" alt="" src="http://ddcdn.azureedge.net/images/promo17.jpg" class="video" alt="Development Dialogue 2017 Promo Video" />
            </div>
            <div id="thevideo" style="display: none;">
                <embed width="350" height="290" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/WHGFYQ3o5vY?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;autoplay=1" taget=_blank frameborder="0" allowfullscreen/>
            </div>
```

This code I have added in my Cordova application to embed YouTube video its working in browser but not in my android phone please send me answer the video should open onclick instead of redirecting to YouTube page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to play the video within the app, then you can embed a video player in the app which plays the video for you.

I have tried a simple and straight forward [cordova video player plugin](https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer) which works fine. This player plays the video and auto closes by itself. It also porvides volume and scaling mode controls too. Hope it helps. Check out

Comment: Are you sure that youtube video will play within ios application ?

Comment: @KirankumarDafda tested in android device and it works. This plugin is meant only for android. In iOS, You can use HTML5 video tag to playback video inside your application.

Comment: Yes, it is because I have tested embeded video into android and ios, working in android only, and HTML5 video tag will work in ios app but still not sure about youtube links.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda Right... this is android only plugin.